# How do you put a Form in a SwiftUI Modal?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-form

I'm trying to create a modal containing a Form in SwiftUI. I'd prefer not to use action sheets in favor of a modal similar to the one pictured below. It seems as though SwiftUI Modals and Alerts aren't capable of such modals yet, is there a possible solution?

[image]

Comment: Can’t you just use a ZStack and show the form on top of the current view?

Comment: Maybe use a semi-transparent dark background and a ZStack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Two approaches

Here are two examples of ways to create a custom modal.

---

### 1. With `.overlay()`

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View { // your main view
    @State var showModal: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Button(action: {
                self.showModal.toggle()
            }) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                    Text("Show Modal")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Welcome")
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        .overlay(ModalView(showModal: $showModal))
    }
}

struct ModalView: View { // draws a semi-transparent rectangle that contains the modal
    @Binding var showModal: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if showModal {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(0.5))
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .overlay(
                        GeometryReader { geometry in
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .frame(width: min(geometry.size.width - 100, 300), height: min(geometry.size.height - 100, 200))
                                .overlay(ModalContentView(showModal: self.$showModal))
                        }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ModalContentView: View { // the real modal content
    @Binding var showModal: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Modal Content")

            Button(action: {
                self.showModal.toggle()
            }) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                    Text("Close Modal")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

### 2. With ZStack

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showModal: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.showModal.toggle()
                    }
                }) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                            .imageScale(.large)
                        Text("Show Modal")
                    }
                }

                if showModal {
                    Rectangle() // the semi-transparent overlay
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(0.5))
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

                    GeometryReader { geometry in // the modal container
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(width: min(geometry.size.width - 100, 300), height: min(geometry.size.height - 100, 200))
                            .overlay(ModalContentView(showModal: self.$showModal))
                    }
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))

                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Welcome")

        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct ModalContentView: View {
    @Binding var showModal: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Modal Content")

            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.showModal.toggle()
                }
            }) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                    Text("Close Modal")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe this second approach is even better. With this one, I also got the animation a kind of working.

Answer (score 2):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var flag = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Title").font(.largeTitle)
                Toggle(isOn: $flag) {
                    Text("Show Moda' on")
                }.padding(100)
                Spacer()
            }.disabled(flag)

            if flag {
                Color.gray.opacity(0.4).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                VStack {
                    Text("label")
                    Button(action: {
                        self.flag.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Close")
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 300, height: 200, alignment: .center)
                .background(Color.primary.colorInvert()).cornerRadius(50)

            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]